# why this update query in c# Windows Forms doesn't work?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-update

i have written this update query with query builder :

```
UPDATE       Users
SET                UserName = ?, UserPassword = ?, UserScore = ?
WHERE        (UserName = ?)
```

and i want to use this query in this part of my Program:

```
if (isLogged == true)       
{
    string isLoggedName = registerLogin.loginUserName;
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format($"New Score for User {isLoggedName} has been Registered ! => {score}"));
        usersTableAdapter.UpdateQuery(isLoggedName, registerLogin.loginPassword, score, isLoggedName);
        usersTableAdapter.Fill(flappyBirdDBDataSet.Users);
    }
    else if (isRegistered == true)
    {
        string isRegisteredName = registerLogin.RegisterUserName;
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format($"New Score for User {isRegisteredName} has been Registered ! => {score}"));
        usersTableAdapter.UpdateQuery(isRegisteredName, registerLogin.RegisterPassword, score, isRegisteredName);
        usersTableAdapter.Fill(flappyBirdDBDataSet.Users);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't show the `isRegisteredName` in the Message Box and also doesn't update the table.

I would be very thankful if you help me.

Comment: Cleartext Passwords. Then rather don't use any in the first place.

Comment: It's not necessary to use [String.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-6.0) when using [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). Also, [MessageBox.Show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) is blocking. It's better to use [System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline?view=net-6.0) for debugging.

Comment: You may consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing. If applicable, adding images to your post may also be beneficial. The information/code you've added is _minimal_, but unfortunately isn't sufficient to re-create the issue. The following may be helpful [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).